# Install Tensorflow 2.3.0 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I can't find a way to install tensorflow on Raspberry PI. I tried:

- **cross-compile on Ubuntu 18.04**: failed because of missing h-files for arm. Ubuntu python installation misses these files
- **compile on Raspberry PI**: build fails with the error "_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ruy24Kernel8bitNeonOutOfOrderERKNS_16KernelParams8bitILi4ELi2EEE"
- **download official whl**: raspberrypi/tensorflow-2.3.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl. It requires python3.5, but python3.5 is broken. Can't even install numpy on it. Error: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf

**How can I install tensorflow 2.3.0 or 2.3.1 on Raspberry PI with the latest Raspberry OS image?**

Answer (score 2):

Although your issue is probably solved, maybe this will help someone else: tensorflow only runs on 64bit-systems. So in case you are working on a 32 bit OS, you need to re-install a 64 bit OS, which should not cause issues on a RPi 4. Afterwards, everything worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your great contribution. I can't test it now, but I'm sure, it will help others :)

Answer (score 1):

I am hving similar isue building on RPi, though not exact same symbol.
As a workaround,you can download the whl from this link.
https://github.com/Qengineering/Tensorflow-Raspberry-Pi

Comment: This is a good solution, if security is not important for you. In my case I can only use official binaries. :(  AND there is also no Tensorflow 2.3.0 whl package....